# Tracking newer ERC20 tokens in a portfolio manager type of app

Tags: tokens, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Currently I'm using Blockfolio to track my portfolio of ERC20 tokens and other non-erc20 tokens that I input manually. But many times blockfolio doesn't have newer coins that are on coingecko or even coinmarketcap.

Is there another type of portfolio token tracker like blockfolio that pulls in data from coingecko or coinmarketcap that I can input manually?

Answer (score 0):

there are many of those out there.

there are a lot of them on binance smart chain look up

poocoin.app lets you input manually as well as auto pulls in tokens

Dex.guru

1inch.io is a slightly better known. there are a lot of other ones out there.